# setState triggers child UseEffect with props as dependency

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which receives as a prop a setState hook from its parent component. When it calls that prop causes a re-render since parent updates its state.

The thing is that I have a useEffect inside the child component that needs to be run only when props change (props is the only dependency it has). But since its parent re-renders it will be executed even when it's not need and I don't know a way to prevent it. I think parent rerender send the props again to the child.

Attaching a basic reproduction of my issue

```
function Parent = () => {
     const [test, setTest] = useState()
     

     return (
        <Child onClick={value => setTest(value)} propINeed={{foo: 'bar'}}/>
     )
}


function Child = props => {
   useEffect(() => {
      //STUFF I NEED TO RUN ONLY WHEN PROPS DO REALLY CHANGE
   }, [props])

   //ONCLICK PROP IS CALLED, AND useEffect RUNS AGAIN, messing with my data
}
```

I know props don't change. So I'm pretty sure it's due to the parent re-render

Comment: Its because on every `setTest`. New function copy is created that's why your `useEffect` run every time

Comment: add only the prop you need in the `useEffect()` dependency array.

Answer (score 1):

Put only the `propINeed` into the dependency array, so the `useEffect` callback doesn't run on click:

```
useEffect(() => {
   //STUFF I NEED TO RUN ONLY WHEN PROPS DO REALLY CHANGE
}, [props.propINeed])
```

Comment: That won't work since `propINeed` is an object that is recreated on every render. The real issue here is not understanding the difference between values that are compared by value and values that are compared by reference. Functions and objects are compared by _reference_, and since that reference is recreated every render it's always different than the last reference. You can fix it by using something like a string or number instead, or memoizing the value that you pass as a prop to the component.